# Python Selenium WebDriver: Chrome not reachable (raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) WebDriverException: chrome not reachable)

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

the problem I have is that I'm using Selenium WebDriver on Python and am continuously getting the 'chrome not reachable' message. I have tried all the suggested fixes from previous posts so I can confirm that Selenium is up-to-date, as is Chrome and the WebDriver version is the required version for said Chrome version. When I run the code, the test Chrome loads with "data;" and after a while it automatically shuts with the "chrome not reachable" message then showing. I really don't know what more to do. It was working perfectly fine before so not really sure what has changed (I am rerunning old code). Any help would be appreciated!

Code:

```
PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
```

Error:

```
File "C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

WebDriverException: chrome not reachable
```

Comment: 1) Selenium 2) Chrome and 3) ChromeDriver version info please?

Comment: 1) Selenium 4.4.3; 2) Chrome 104.0.5112.102; 3) ChromeDriver 104.0.5112.79

Comment: Update the question with the entire error stacktrace.

Comment: Have updated the q

Comment: My Chrome has updated to Version 105.0.5195.102 so I downloaded ChromeDriver Version 105 but still same error